# I want to display data in Table format using json when i try to convert JSON OBJ into array

Tags: android, json

I am trying to convert `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`, but there is some issue. My code is:

```
public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
    ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(json_data.getInt("cus_id"));
            user.setName(json_data.getString("cus_Name"));
            user.setPlace(json_data.getString("cus_city"));
            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return users;
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-30 17:30:16.152 5956-5956/com.example.vari.table_format E/log_tag:
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value
{"Customer_mas":[{"Id":8,"cus_id":"CUS0001","cus_Name":"SUNRISE ELECTRONICS","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  7:20AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  7:20AM"},{"Id":9,"cus_id":"CUS0002","cus_Name":"LGB VAYAMPALAYAM","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  7:56AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  7:56AM"},{"Id":10,"cus_id":"CUS0003","cus_Name":"LGB ANNUR","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  7:56AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  7:56AM"},{"Id":31,"cus_id":"CUS0024","cus_Name":"INTELLE ENGG","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM"},{"Id":32,"cus_id":"CUS0025","cus_Name":"JAAZ ELECTRO","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM"},{"Id":33,"cus_id":"CUS0026","cus_Name":"JEEVAN ELECTRONICS","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM"},{"Id":34,"cus_id":"CUS0027","cus_Name":"J.K.R ENGINERS","cus_city":"COIMBATORE","Created_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM","Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013  8:07AM"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

JSON response:

```
{
   "Customer_mas":[
      {
         "Id":8,
         "cus_id":"CUS0001",
         "cus_Name":"SUNRISE ELECTRONICS",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 7:20AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 7:20AM"
      },
      {
         "Id":9,
         "cus_id":"CUS0002",
         "cus_Name":"LGB VAYAMPALAYAM",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 7:56AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 7:56AM"
      },
      {
         "Id":10,
         "cus_id":"CUS0003",
         "cus_Name":"LGB ANNUR",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 7:56AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 7:56AM"
      },
      {
         "Id":31,
         "cus_id":"CUS0024",
         "cus_Name":"INTELLE ENGG",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM"
      },
      {
         "Id":32,
         "cus_id":"CUS0025",
         "cus_Name":"JAAZ ELECTRO",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM"
      },
      {
         "Id":33,
         "cus_id":"CUS0026",
         "cus_Name":"JEEVAN ELECTRONICS",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM"
      },
      {
         "Id":34,
         "cus_id":"CUS0027",
         "cus_Name":"J.K.R ENGINERS",
         "cus_city":"COIMBATORE",
         "Created_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM",
         "Updated_date":"Nov 20 2013 8:07AM"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Show `result ` String also

Comment: What do you see in the logcat? Please update your question with that.

Comment: `public class Users {

    int cus_id;
    String cus_Name;
    String cus_city;

    public int getId() {
        return cus_id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.cus_id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return cus_Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.cus_Name = name;
    }
    public String getPlace() {
        return cus_city;
    }
    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.cus_city = place;
    }

}
`

Comment: post your json response

Comment: in my logcat to display all json values

Comment: @karthiventure no, we don't need to know your Java class. All we need is **1.** Logcat, **2.** your JSON response.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @karthiventure instead of parsing the `Users` POJO in here, parse it inside the object, that is pass the JSON string in the constructor of `Users`.

Comment: Hi are you from `Annur`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pars your data like this.

```
public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
    ArrayList<Users> userList  = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Customer_mas");
        for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(jsonData.getInt("id"));
            user.setCus_id(jsonData.getString("cus_id"));
            user.setName(jsonData.getString("cus_Name"));
            user.setPlace(jsonData.getString("cus_city"));
            userList.add(user);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userList;
}
```

if your POJO object type for id is string then definitely it will work.

Paste this code inside the Users.java class

```
public class Users {
String cus_id;
String name;
String place;
int id;


public Users() {
    this.cus_id = "";
    this.name = "";
    this.place = "";
    this.id = 0;

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCus_id() {
    return cus_id;
}

public void setCus_id(String cus_id) {
    this.cus_id = cus_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}
```

}

Comment: No this is also not fix my problem @Pradeep

Comment: but it is working for me, I have tested it with your json string.

Comment: just copy paste the compete function and try to run it, it must work, if not then post the error.

Comment: this is my another class file User.class

Comment: int cus_id;
    String cus_Name;
    String cus_city;

    public int getId() {
        return cus_id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.cus_id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return cus_Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.cus_Name = name;
    }
    public String getPlace() {
        return cus_city;
    }
    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.cus_city = place;
    }

Comment: @karthiventure dude, you're making me cringe :P Why are you not providing us what we are asking you for? Again, we don't care about you POJOs because they are not what are causing the errors. Paste your Logcat.

Comment: Sorry bro actually i just post code but format was not working

Comment: @karthiventure if it didn't work, logcat can tell us why. Can you please share it?

Comment: just change cus_id data type as String in POJO object and then run it with my answer code, because your data type is different to json value.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh after use your code i get this error "setid(int) in view  cannot be applied to java.lang.string"

Comment: @karthiventure that is an easy fix. I guess I'm not gonna help you with that. Rest assured, this is the correct answer. You should accept it.

Comment: for that I am telling you change the data type of your cus_id. like this  String cus_id; in your  POJO object (Users.java)

Comment: @karthiventure if you really wish to be spoonfed, just replace `user.setId(jsonData.getString("cus_id"));` with `user.setId(jsonData.getInt("cus_id"));`

Comment: see this i change into String  ' String cus_id;' 'public String getId() {
        return cus_id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.cus_id = id;
    }'

Comment: i also chage into Users.java file

Comment: i get this error "setid(int) in view cannot be applied to java.lang.string this is the error

Comment: wait I am giving you POJO object and copy past as it.

Comment: yes @Sufian i chage into getInt("cus_id") but id is not integer also change into String

Comment: see the edited answer copy paste the code, do not forget the { that is in next line.

Comment: @karthiventure what are you doing? You're mixing what I said with Pradeep. Just pick one advice (his or mine) and the error will go away. Don't mix two different pieces of advice.

Comment: yes i add your code into Users.java file same error in my MainActivity file wait i will post my MainActivity file

Comment: I need solution I test with Both of you advices @Sufian

Comment: I just update my code(Main Activity) @PradeepDeshmukh

Comment: @karthiventure okay but please understand what you're going.

Comment: I have edited the code please check, and also replace code in your MainActivity with label.setId(p.getId());

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
   JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("Customer_mas");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setId(json_data.getString("cus_id"));
        user.setName(json_data.getString("cus_Name"));
        user.setPlace(json_data.getString("cus_city"));
        users.add(user);
```

Comment: after use code @Annop Kanya i get this error in Logcat :Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value CUS0001 at cus_id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Comment: use getString method instead

Comment: NOPE bro same error LOGCAT:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "CUS0001"

Comment: change your user class and make cus_id a String rather than an int.

Comment: cus_id is a string, not an int

Comment: If you have changed it to String then it will work fine.

Comment: i change into String data type

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

    addHeader();

    for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

        Users p = (Users) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText(p.getName());
        label.setId(p.getCus_id()); //here is the problem 
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        place.setText(p.getPlace());
        place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        place.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(place,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

label.setId(p.getCus_id()); //here is the problem

Comment: replace it with label.setCus_id(p.getCus_id());

Comment: yes i already change it but here we are going to set ID for that label?correct?then how we are going to setCus_id?

Comment: so why were you trying to set there cus_id, Omg! you are passing wrong data to wrong place and created confusion for me too. you did not parse the data for id. you have to parse the id first then you will be able to set there id.

Comment: you mean order is changed?

Comment: see my answer i have change and try it, it must work if you are doing all correct.

Comment: @karthiventure is that a new question? Didn't Pradeep solved your original problem? To get familiar with the rules of SO, please go through this once - [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i will try @Pradeep

Comment: @karthiventure i have fixed your Json parsing problem, this is another problem that you are facing. for an advice you must understand first basic concept of JAVA, then move on to Android. I tried my best to solve your problem. All the best :)

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh afetr update your code this line indicating error user.setId(jsonData.getString("cus_id"));

Comment: look into my code both code POJO object and the parsing function take as it same. you are setting wrong data to wrong place. if you want to set cus_id set it into setCus_id method, setId is for your id. and both values data type is different, cus_id is string type, id is integer type. when you are parsing you have to set and get data into POJO object according to its correct data type.